# PHP PDO statement to filter records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP PDO to retrieve objects to an iOS app via JSON.
There is a database table with event objects. It has three fields to store day, month and year. The owner of the database doesn't want to store dates in a date field, that means that I have to deal with it.

The app sends a URL with params,like this:

```
http://..hidden domain./myfile.php?dia_inicio=16&dia_final=15&mes_inicio=11&mes_final=12&ano_inicio=2014&ano_final=2015
```

That means that I am looking for events from 16Nov2014 to 15Dec2015.

This is my PHP code:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbagenda  WHERE  (dia_evento => :di AND mes_evento = :mi AND ano_evento = :ai) OR (dia_evento <= :df AND mes_evento = :mf AND ano_evento = :af) ';

    // use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good practice
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindParam(':di', $dia_inicio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':df', $dia_final, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mi', $mes_inicio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mf', $mes_final, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ai', $ano_inicio, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':af', $ano_final, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // fetch the results into an array
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    // convert to json
    $json = json_encode( $result );

    // echo the json string
    echo $json
```

How should I change my statement to make it work with dates like: 16Nov2014 to 28Nov2014 (same month), 16Nov2014 to 5Dec2014 (different month, same year) and 16Nov2014 to 02May2015(different year)?

ADDED LATER:

iOS log to show the URL send to the PHP file:

```
recuperar_eventos_dia.php?dia_inicio=11&dia_final=26&mes_inicio=11&mes_final=11&ano_inicio=2014&ano_final=2014
```

PHP part:

```
$start = "$ano_inicio-$mes_inicio-$dia_inicio";
$end = "$ano_final-$mes_final-$dia_final";

// In the SQL, concatenate the columns to make a YYYY-MM-DD date string
// and cast it to a MySQL DATE type.
// That makes it possible to use BETWEEN
$sql = 'SELECT 
  *
FROM tbagenda  
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', ano_evento, mes_evento, dia_evento), "%Y-%m-%d") 
     BETWEEN :start AND :end';

// Bind and execute the statement with 2 parameters:
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// fetch, etc...
$result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

        // convert to json
        $json = json_encode( $result );

        // echo the json string
        echo $json;
```

And now a screenshot from the table tbagenda:
[image]

Comment: _The owner of the database doesn't want to store dates in a date field_ - why ever not? At the very least add a proper Date field in addition to make this sort of problem tractable.

Comment: @MikeW, thank you for your comment, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry that you're stuck with this unfortunate table structure.

I would suggest concatenating the table's columns to form usable date strings, and cast them to a date value via MySQL's built in function [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).  Do the same with your query string input values to make proper date comparisons with a `BETWEEN` operator.

```
// Begin by concatenating the input values into single date strings YYYY-MM-DD
$start = "$ano_inicio-$mes_inicio-$dia_inicio";
$end = "$ano_final-$mes_final-$dia_final";

// In the SQL, concatenate the columns to make a YYYY-MM-DD date string
// and cast it to a MySQL DATE type.
// That makes it possible to use BETWEEN
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM tbagenda  
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', ano_evento, mes_evento, dia_evento), '%Y-%m-%d') 
          BETWEEN :start AND :end";

// Bind and execute the statement with 2 parameters:
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// fetch, etc...
$result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

The string operations will affect performance of this query. It would be better, as you know, if the dates were stored as a proper `DATE` so MySQL would not need to cast them for comparisons. They could also then be indexed.

Note also that I did not include validation of the date strings.  You might consider checking them to be sure they make valid dates before executing the query.

```
// strtotime() would return false for invalid date strings...
if (strtotime($start) && strtotime($end)) {
  // The dates are valid, and so you can proceed with the query
  $sql = 'SELECT.....';
}
```

Comment: Than you Michael, your answer is a very clever solution to the problem, but the output is a blank array, and there are at least 5 records that match the query.

Comment: When you say the output is blank, do you mean the whole screen is blank? If so, that could be because of the syntax problem from before I changed single to double wuotes on the SQL string.  Always debug queries separate from your PHP code. Use a MySQL client to test it with static values like `BETWEEN '2014-11-16' AND '2015-05-02'`. Once you have it working in a MySQL client, you can go back to the PHP to debug it there. I could easily have typos here.

Comment: No, the array is [], as I checked in the internet browser executing the php file with written params.

Comment: It should not be necessary to cast the $start and $end strings to dates, even if they are not zero-padded, which results in dates like 2014-5-1 instead of 2014-05-01.  As I said, get the SQL query to work by itself in a MySQL client before testing it in PHP.

Comment: I have changed the single quotes to double quotes and also two - that should be _, thank you in any case.

Comment: I thought I might miss a `-` instead of `_`. Here is a small proof that the query should work :-) good luck. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05f62e/4

Comment: I think I should insist and convince the data base owner to create a date field in order to avoid this problem now, and other problems in the future, don't you think so?

Comment: @novato Yes, I agree. I makes very good sense to have a single proper date field, if only to take advantage of the database's built in date support functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: The statement in your answer is different to the statement at sqlfiddle, on the second you have added 'as d'

Comment: @novato That was only to show the date in the `SELECT` list. You'll notice that on sqlfiddle, I placed the whole `CONCAT_WS()` expression into the `SELECT` instead of `SELECT *`. For your purposes, you would be more concerned with `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thank you, I have learned a lot from your answer, but you say that it should work, but it doesn't. I will put now in my question the statement as I have it now in my PHP file, the data base table, and the URL sent by the iOS app, so you can see if I have done correctly what you say.

Comment: Michael, you are kindly requested to check out the added parts to my question, may be you can find why it is not working as you expect. Thank you again for your time and patience.

Comment: As a start, the query definitely works when hard-coding your same values. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c276/2 Let me experiment a moment to see if PDO does any strange handling with dates.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it - a quoting problem on the `'-'` inside `CONCAT_WS`.  You have it single-quoted when the SQL string is single quoted. That makes the craziest thing happen: it results in the _arithmetic_ operation `'string' - 'string'`, which results in zero because of PHP's typecasting rules. The statement is probably throwing an uncaught error if you haven't set `$dbh` to throw exceptions.  `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO:ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Thank you very much, you are great, and a very nice person. You have 139k reputation and don't mind helping me with my 18 votes...